# XSLT: XPATH operator "less than or equal to" calculates incorrectly

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm using the following XSLT expression

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="@month">
     <xsl:sort select="@chartmonth" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
     <xsl:variable name="vCURRENTMONTH" select="@chartmonth"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="round(sum([@chartmonth &lt;= $vCURRENTMONTH]/@sum) *100) div 100"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

To calculate values per month. This works fine, however, when @chartmonth equals 10, the calculation is done only for months 1 and 10, i.e. it adds the sum of month 1 and 10, but it 'forgets', months 2 to 9.
When the @chartmonth equals 9 (or any other number), the calculation is correct.

Even more strange, when I alter the code to:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="@month">
     <xsl:sort select="@chartmonth" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
     <xsl:variable name="vCURRENTMONTH" select="@chartmonth"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="round(sum([@chartmonth+0 &lt;= $vCURRENTMONTH+0]/@sum) *100) div 100"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

The calculation is always correct, even when @chartmonth equals 10.

Does any know what I'm doing wrong or what is causing this issue?

Many thanks,

EDIT 1:
INPUT is:

```
<rows>
  <row month="Jan" chartmonth="1" sum="394.66"/>
  <row month="Feb" chartmonth="2" sum="435.37"/>
  <row month="Mar" chartmonth="3" sum="424.42"/>
  <row month="Apr" chartmonth="4" sum="376.73"/>
  <row month="May" chartmonth="5" sum="418.18"/>
  <row month="Jun" chartmonth="6" sum="404.54"/>
  <row month="Jul" chartmonth="7" sum="466.78"/>
  <row month="Aug" chartmonth="8" sum="475.36"/>
  <row month="Sep" chartmonth="9" sum="502.21"/>
  <row month="Oct" chartmonth="10" sum="46.82"/>
</rows>
```

Comment: I doubt that `sum([@chartmonth &lt;= $vCURRENTMONTH]/@sum)` compiles so consider to show us a minimal but complete input and XSLT sample allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: input:    <row month="Jan" chartmonth="1" sum="394.66"/>
    <row month="Feb" chartmonth="2" sum="435.37"/>
    <row month="Mar" chartmonth="3" sum="424.42"/>
    <row month="Apr" chartmonth="4" sum="376.73"/>
    <row month="May" chartmonth="5" sum="418.18"/>
    <row month="Jun" chartmonth="6" sum="404.54"/>
    <row month="Jul" chartmonth="7" sum="466.78"/>
    <row month="Aug" chartmonth="8" sum="475.36"/>
    <row month="Sep" chartmonth="9" sum="502.21"/>
    <row month="Oct" chartmonth="10" sum="46.82"/>

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the input sample as a code snippet. It should be minimal but complete, as your XSLT snippet does `select="result"` I would expect to see some `result` elements.

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully it is more clear now, thanks!

Comment: Invalid statement `round(sum([@chartmonth &lt;= $vCURRENTMONTH]/@sum) *100) div 100`.

Comment: Should it be `select="row"` and not `select="rows"`? Also, can you show the output you are expecting for your given input? Thanks!

Comment: select row, correct, question edited. Output is actually a chart using javascript (FlotChart), so difficult to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 (and XPath 2.0) the effect of the comparison operators `<`, `<=`, etc, depends on the data types of the operands.

Assuming that your stylesheet isn't schema-aware, comparing two attributes (like `@month &lt; $other/@month`) is a comparison between two untypedAtomic values, and these are compared as strings: so "10" < "2". To get a numeric comparison, convert either or both values to numbers: `xs:integer(@month) &lt; xs:integer($other/@month)`, or for brevity `+@month &lt; +$other/@month`

(If your stylesheet is schema-aware and `@month` is declared in the schema with a numeric type, then the comparison will be done numerically as you are expecting.)